# Should I provide ostream << operators for types in a library?

Tags: c++, libraries, iostream, idioms, debug-print

I'm working on a C++ wrapper library for some API. Suppose I've implemented some struct or class type `Foo`. I can't make up my mind whether or not to provide an `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Foo& x)` with my library.

On one hand:

- It's convenient for debugging.
- It doesn't interfere with the rest of the code.
- I don't expect `Foo`s to be printed except when debugging, so this shouldn't clash with users wanting to serialize `Foo`s to files or similar activities.

On the other hand:

- It's not necessary, i.e. the wrappers' functionality does not require it for anything.
- Library users might want to some other debug-printing format, different than what I write. Or maybe they use Antony Polukhin's dark voodoo automatic struct printing ([magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get)).
- Unless carefully separated from the rest of the code, it forces the library user to include `<iostreams>`, which is not a trivial thing.

Am ignoring some other primal consideration for any of the options? Or, to put it different: What would be an appropriate criterion for including such operators with the library?

Additional info:

- All of `Foo`s members can be obtained by the user, so they don't need a member or a friend function to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Personally I like the `to_string` idiom.  Expose a method that stringifies the object, and people can use that as needed.

Comment: @NathanOliver: 1. But practically nothing in the libraries I know has a `to_string()` method. I doubt there even that many overloads of a freestanding `to_string()`... 2. The fundamental dilemma remains, whether it's the ostream'ing operator or `to_string()`... 3. There's also `operator std::string()`.

Comment: `#ifndef NDEBUG <your operator<< overloads and necessary includes> #endif`. Personally I like when the library maker supplies this, even though it's not going to be used in production.

Comment: Is there some attribute or property of your class that is not gettable by the user? In other words, is the user of your class able to sufficiently implement this operator using the existing interface?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: That's a good point. The user can obtain all the information I use to implement the streaming operator. Also, it's a non-friend freestanding function, so obviously yes.

Comment: Any output from your lib should also work for host app's that are not console/terminal based. Decouple from the output and let the users decide on their favourite output mechanism.

Comment: @ChefGladiator: We're talking about streaming to ostream's. non-console apps either don't stream at all, or stream into some buffer that goes into a textbox, or whatever. So I don't think that particular consideration affects my decision. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @einpoklum consider server-side components, or iot or medical equipment. there is no "stdbox" or any UI and there is no stdout or stderr, very often there is only `syslog()`  One can be attracted to streaming and develop a solution in such a scenario that is true. Personally  I prefer `{fmt}` to streaming.

Comment: @ChefGladiator: Sure, but that doesn't seem to have bearing on my dilemma.